# How to get the name of variable using it's index in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data that looks like this

```
Name      A    B    C    D    E
r1        1    5    12  21    15
r2        2    4     7  10     9
r3        5   15     6   9     6
r4        7    8     0   7    18
```

My question is how can i get the name of variable using it's index

for example if i want the name of index number 1 the name that will return is "A"

thank you

Comment: Not clear about what you meant by index.  Is it column index?  then, the 1 should give 'Name' as column because the column index is 1

Answer (score 1):

Use the `colnames()` function then index the vector that produces.

```
colnames(mtcars)[1]
```

That would return the name of the first variable in `mtcars`. Just change the name of the data.frame to match yours and the number to the variable of interest. E.g the third variable in `iris` is

```
 colnames(iris)[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know which *column* (name) includes the value `1`.

```r
tmp <- colSums(dat == 1) > 0
names(tmp[tmp])
# [1] "A"
```

Walk-through:

1. The `==` returns a matrix with per-position matches:

   ```r
   dat == 1
   #       Name     A     B     C     D     E
   # [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   ```
2. `colSums(.) > 0` tells us which column has at least one `TRUE`:

   ```r
   colSums(dat == 1) > 0
   #  Name     A     B     C     D     E 
   # FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   ```
3. ... and then we take the name of the names found. If none are found, it will return an empty vector:

   ```r
   names(tmp[tmp])
   # character(0)
   ```

The only gotcha I can think of here is if you are doing high-precision floating-point comparison, in which case IEEE-754 comes into play (see [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518), [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004), and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). For that, consider a test of inequality with tolerance instead of a strict test of equality.

This requires that we only look at numeric columns.

```r
isnum <- sapply(dat, is.numeric)
isnum
#  Name     A     B     C     D     E 
# FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 

tmp <- colSums(abs(dat[,isnum] - 1) < 1e-5) > 0
#                      ,^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^.
#   subset the data --'                   
# ... and a test of inequality within tolerance
names(tmp[tmp])
# [1] "A"
```

Comment: JQQ: Whats the purpose of sapply? cant `dat == 1` just work? curious though

Comment: Yup, of course you're right, was going down different rabbit holes and didn't undo that. Thanks!